# Regex - match multiple unordered words in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a list of names and I am looking to filter the list to only return names that contains both the last and first names.

Let's say I am looking for "Joe Doe"

I have the current regex `(?:^|\s)Joe|(?:^|\s)Doe`

It somewhat works but it is returning all the strings that contains either Joe or Doe. I would like it to match the names that contains both names only, and it could be either "Doe Joe" or "Joe Doe"

Comment: is your first name and last name always separated by whitespace?

Comment: Not always, there are cases where I have hyphenated names

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This lookahead based regex should work:

```
/(?=.*?\bJoe\b)(?=.*?\bDoe\b).*/i
```

**Testing:**

```
/(?=.*?\bJoe\b)(?=.*?\bDoe\b).*/.test('Joe Doe'); // true
/(?=.*?\bJoe\b)(?=.*?\bDoe\b).*/.test('Doe Joe'); // true
```

Comment: That will match Joel Adoe

Comment: I need it to match Names that start with as well...therefore 'Joe Do' should also match 'Joe Doe'

Comment: @Newton: In that case take out word boundaries `\b` from both sides

Comment: How can I prevent it from finding names that contains the name? i.e. return false when looking for "Doe" in "McDoe"?